# Clone rows of a datagridview that has a specific value on a column

Tags: c#

I'm using this to clone datagridview values and then fill a dataset and make a report.

**What I tried so far:**

```
DataGridView dat = new DataGridView();

        if (dat.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvc in dgvMenuMisDocumentos.Columns)
            {
                dat.Columns.Add(dgvc.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
            }
        }

        DataGridViewRow rad = new DataGridViewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < dgvMenuMisDocumentos.RowCount; i++)
        {

            IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> rows = dgvMenuMisDocumentos.Rows
         .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
         .Where(r => r.Cells["fecha_ingreso"].Value.ToString().Equals(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()));

            if (rows.Count() > 0)
            {
                rad = (DataGridViewRow)dgvMenuMisDocumentos.Rows[i].Clone();
                int clidx = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvMenuMisDocumentos.Rows[i].Cells)
                {
                    rad.Cells[clidx].Value = cell.Value;
                    clidx++;
                }
                dat.Rows.Add(rad);
            }
           return dat; 
        }
```

I expect to show the values on the report but the problem is that the values don´t show.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I did it this way:**

```
DataGridView dat = new DataGridView();

        if (dat.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvc in dgvMenuMisDocumentos.Columns)
            {
                dat.Columns.Add(dgvc.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
            }
        }

        DataGridViewRow rad = new DataGridViewRow();

        var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
        var dater = dateAndTime.Date;
        int k = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dgvMenuMisDocumentos.Rows)
        {
            string state = rw.Cells[dgvMenuMisDocumentos.Columns["fecha_ingreso"].Index].Value.ToString();

            if (state == dater.ToString())
            {
                rad = (DataGridViewRow)dgvMenuMisDocumentos.Rows[k].Clone();
                int clidx = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvMenuMisDocumentos.Rows[k].Cells)
                {
                    rad.Cells[clidx].Value = cell.Value;
                    clidx++;
                }
                dat.Rows.Add(rad);
            }
            k++;
        }

        return dat;
```